# Convert HashMap of HashMap into ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, hashmap

I know convert HashMap into List can be done by `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(hashMap.values());`, But how about HashMap of HashMap? 

Like: `HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>`, how to convert it into `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`? 

My idea so far is `List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList(hashMap.values());`, but how to convert inner HashMap into list with/without iterate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-java 8 you can use

1.) Fetch entry set from your `hashMapOfMaps`

2.) `hashMapOfMaps.getValue()` will `retrun` `HashMap<String, String>` and then `.values()` return the `String` values of inner map

```
    for (Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> entry:  hashMapOfMaps.entrySet()) {
        listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>(entry.getValue().values()));
    }                                                 |            |
                                                   inner-Map       |
                                                                   |
                                                      inner-Map's string values
```

Answer (score 2):

```
map.values().stream()  // a stream of Map<String, String>
    .map(innerMap -> new ArrayList<>(innerMap.values())  // a stream of List<String>
    .collect(Collectors.toList());  // List of List<String>
```

Of course, you lose all key information.

Comment: where does `innerMap` come from? there is no variable that contain value of inner map isn't it?

Comment: `innerMap -> new ArrayList<>(innerMap.values())` is a Lambda, you can give the variable in the definition any name, and you can use it in the function part.  `x -> new ArrayList<>(x.values())` would also have worked, but is less readable.  However, it will depend on if Java 8 is available for you, it depends on which Android API version you are developing for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want this on android you might not want to use Java 8 streams. Here for JDK 7

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> mapOpfMap = new HashMap<>();
List<List<String>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>();

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>>> it = mapOpfMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry<String, HashMap<String, String>> value = it.next();
        value.getKey(); // here is the key if you need it
        listOfList.add(new ArrayList<>(value.getValue().values()));
    }
```